# Google Analytics in Android : How send 'non interaction' events?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I want to send non interaction events so that it not get counted in sessions? In 'Google Analytics for web' there is such option but couldn't find anything similar in Android. Any leads would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it, no documentation exists though.

```
Tracker t = mApplication.getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
    // Build and send an Event.
    t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder().setCategory(category)
            .setAction(action).setLabel(label).setNonInteraction(true).build());
```